# Is there a way to enable logging in the Here Android SDK?

Tags: here-api

The Here android SDK contains lots of log messages, but they go through a wrapper for the Android Log class, that by default does not actually log these messages. Is there a way to make it actually log these messages?

Im able to set a breakpoint in a decompiled class, bg.class, in the static init block, and set a = null, and that enables logging, but it seems like there must be a better and less tedious way to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry that is not supported :)

What would you like to achieve turning on logs? Generally our logs contains logs of trace messages that are not useful for 3rd party developers.

Comment: Having worked with your SDK, i cant imagine any way i could have made it work without enabling verbose logging.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What kind of information would be helpful?